# install multiple os in pendrive using grub

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a pendrive 16gb transcend.
I want to install `lubuntu` and `kali` in it(live cd image, may be using dd). 
When I plug in this thumb to a pc it have to show a `grub bootloader` and have to able to choose any one of the os.

Any one have any idea?

what I am thinking is to install grub in it(thumb drive) and point to the two memory locations of these os's. I don't Know this will work. But I need some expert advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know one package to do that: **LiveUSB MultiBoot**. I haven't tested it but it seems that support lots of distributions.

Please find it there: http://bit.ly/1PcScm8